# Difference between EXACT and INTERSECTING LocationMatchingStrategy in google sheets API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

According to google sheets api documentation, `LocationMatchingStrategy` can be one of `EXACT` or `INTERSECTING`.

> Determines how this lookup matches the location. If this field is specified as EXACT, only developer metadata associated on the exact location specified is matched. If this field is specified to INTERSECTING, developer metadata associated on intersecting locations is also matched. If left unspecified, this field assumes a default value of INTERSECTING. If this field is specified, a metadataLocation must also be specified.

However, I'm unable to understand this statement. What is "developer metadata associated with exact location"? How this matching works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `INSERSECTING` and `EXACT` is clarified in [DeveloperMetadataLocationMatchingStrategy](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter#developermetadatalocationmatchingstrategy):

> **EXACT_LOCATION**:   Indicates that a specified location should be matched exactly. For example, if row three were specified as a location this matching strategy would only match developer metadata also associated on row three. Metadata associated on other locations would not be considered.

> **INTERSECTING_LOCATION**: Indicates that a specified location should match that exact location as well as any intersecting locations. For example, if row three were specified as a location this matching strategy would match developer metadata associated on row three as well as metadata associated on locations that intersect row three. **If, for instance, there was developer metadata associated on column B, this matching strategy would also match that location because column B intersects row three**.

Where the location refers to the [DeveloperMetadataLocation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata#DeveloperMetadata.DeveloperMetadataLocation) specified on the [DeveloperMetadataLookup](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter#DeveloperMetadataLookup).

Comment: Maybe someone will come back and answer this question. I don't mean to be difficult but the "Intersection" is an exclusive relation (x AND y) whereas what is described in the sentance below is actually (x OR y) "indicates that a specified location should match that exact location as well as (OR) any intersecting locations."   IF this sentence actually described the behavior this ENUM should be "UNION_LOCATION".    This is the source of my confusion on the subject and 'yes' I have read the docs.